# Sphinx c++ documentation : having working links in code-blocks

Tags: c++, dns, python-sphinx

I have written a Sphinx documentation for a C++ API. The class and function reference works fine, with clickable links.

However, if I write a code block with `.. code-block:: cpp`, nothing is recognized as documented class and functions, and they are not clickable.

Is `code-block` not interconnected at all with Sphinx C++ Domain? Is there any workaround?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps the `parsed-literal` directive is what you are looking for? http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#parsed-literal

Comment: I think one may use, `.. code-block:: c` or `.. code-block:: guess`